# Training machine learning model for ecommerce customer/orders models

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, recommendation-engine

I have the following dataset:

```
| customer | item | number_of_orders |
|    1     |  1   |         1        |
|    1     |  2   |         0        |
|    1     |  3   |         0        |
|    1     |  4   |         1        |
|    2     |  1   |         0        |
|    2     |  2   |         0        |
|    2     |  3   |         0        |
|    2     |  4   |         1        |
...
```

I am trying to conclude if the user X would order item Y as a first step.

This is the code that I am having so far

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=7)

model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
result = accuracy_score(Y_test, predictions)
result
```

It is giving a very high accuracy, but I am suspecting that it is related to a large number of zeros in the dataset for `number_of_orders`.

Can someone suggest how to improve on this ML model?

I also have information about the price and item quantity and average price per item, which I thought to use also.

My final goal is to create a recommendation system from this data, to return a list of recommendations based on the other orders.

Comment: Have you tried other ML models different from KNeighborsClassifier? Regressions, suppport vector mahcines,...

Comment: @rgralma I have tried regression. I haven't tried SVM or RandomForest. My final goal is to make a recommendation system based on the data that I have.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly i would suggest changing your evaluation method to a weighted F1 score https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html - make sure to pick 'weighted' option to account for label imbalance. This score is great for your problem.

Second I would try some other models, KNN is a good start but it might not be the case that it is able to find a proper decision boundary to separate your problem. Perhaps try random forest and/or the new histgradientboostingclassifier (similar to lightgbm approach).

You could also try and rephrase your problem and try to solve this as a recommender problem, perhaps you can use some matrix factorization techniques, it would seem very helpful as data in the format you posted is often extremely sparse (lots of 0's).

Comment: Going the route of recommender is my final goal. I would like to see which item would be most suitable for some customer that I ask about. Would you still suggest the same as here for that?

Comment: Yes a recommender definitely makes sense for that approach. I can really recommend LightFM for python :)

Answer (score 1):

You could have a lot of zeros there!  Use the small piece of code sample below to find the percentage of zeros in your dataset.

```
df_missing = df.isna()
df_num_missing = df_missing.sum()
print(df_num_missing / len(df))
print(df.isna().mean().round(4) * 100)
```

I don't know what your threshold would be, but I would surmise that if 50% or more are zero, that's going to be a pretty useless feature.  You could take a subset of non-zero records.

```
df.drop(df[df['number_of_orders'] == 0].index,inplace=True)
```

Try that and see how you get along.  Also, try what other people have suggested.  Some algos are pretty smart about handling zeros, nulls, etc.  I believe Random Forest (regression and classification) are quite robust even when the data sets are mostly junk.

Comment: Thanks! There is a lot of zeros with my approach, as I can see around 95%, because I have mixed and matched all customers with each item, which produce a lot of zeros. My final goal is to build a recommendation system from this